# How to only retrieve the nested document mongodb and spring boot

Tags: spring-boot, spring-data-mongodb

I have the following document and nested document.

```
class Foo {
   public String name;
   public String description;
   public LocalDateTime someDate;
}

@Document
class Bar {
   @Id
   public String id;
   public String details; 
   public List<Foo> foos;
}
```

My custom query looks as follows:

```
 Query query = new Query(
    Criteria.where("foo.name").is("Some name").and("id").is("myId")
 );
 List<Bar> resultList = operations.find(query, Bar.class);
```

I want to retrieve the the single Foo document that matches "Some name". And not the Bar document with the Foo list. How would I do this?
Thanks

Comment: If you want to do that, ask yourself why it is part of `Bar` in the first place?

Comment: True. That's what I wondered as well, but wanted to know if above was possible or not. So it seems not, so the nested document should be @DbRef instead and query that collection

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If your `Foo` class doesn't have a collection in database and it's embedded in `Bar`  as you described in your question. You will need to create a custom repository to get what you are looking for.

```
interface BarRepository extends BarCustomRepository, MongoRepository<Bar, String> {

    }

interface BarCustomRepository {
Foo findFooByName(String fooName);
}


class BarRepositoryImpl implements BarCustomRepository {

@Autiwired
private MongoTemplate mongoTemplate;

@Override
Foo findFooByName(String fooName) {
Bar bar = mongoTemplate.findOne(new Query ( Criteria.where("foos.name").is(fooname)), Bar.class);

Foo foo = bar.getFooByName(fooName);// implement this method in your Bar class. // to Get a foo by fooName from foos list
return foo;
   }
}
```

I hope that helps.

Comment: Thanks, but decided to remove it is a nested document.